# Science Fiction novel which takes place on a large cylindrical spaceship traveling through space

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi

When I was in college in 1987, I read a science fiction book that I'd like to reread. But I cannot remember the name or author.

The key features that I recall, are

- It takes place on a large cylindrical spaceship traveling through space (not orbiting),
- From inside the ship, the human style society extends around the inside walls, so people can see on the other side the opposite habitats,
- The ship rotates to form a gravity well,
- One of the most popular entertainments is to take an elevator up to the center of the cylinder, where you could "rent" a set of wings and fly.

What is the title of this book?

Comment: It sounds like an L5-style space colony, and the date matches that pretty well.

Comment: If it were a short story, "For the birds" by Asimov hits a lot of the main points.

Comment: One of the *Rendezvous with Rama* novels?

Comment: the wings and flying was also a bit in '3001: The Final Odyssey', also included space elevators. Maybe conflating a couple of Clarke stories it seems?

Comment: Also, as it turns out, the setting of Patrick Tomlinson's The Ark (2015), book one of the Children of a Death Earth trilogy: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25848445-the-ark

Comment: I'm not sure I'm thinking of the same work, but I remember something like this where part of the game of "flying" from the near-zero-g zone at the centre of the cylinder was to figure out when/which way to steer to land at a chosen spot on the cylinder, accounting for coriolis effects and the like.

Comment: I think it is Spirals, as per answer below. But really, it could be almost any of the O'Neill stories. If you really are sure about the traveling through space, how about "Down and out on Ellfive prime"?

Comment: Another book set inside an O'Neill cylinder was the first book in the 3rd series of Tom Swift novels https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swift#Third_series_(1981%E2%80%931984) - vaguely recall that the character's wings were sabotaged or damaged in some way and he landed in a lake, then was late starting the space race with his prototype fusion drive-powered ship.

Comment: You can't generate a gravity well by rotation! Any rotating vessel in free space is only simulating the effect of gravity, by its centripetal effect on all free objects within it, which are confined to one internal surface by their inertia. But no gravity well forms: objects external to the vessel are not attracted by it. The rotation only simulates gravity, it cannot generate it.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think the Night's Dawn Trilogy from Peter F. Hamilton has at some of the many arcs of the 6 1000 sided books something like that (flying with wings in such a station).

Comment: Makes me think of two stories: the novel "Rendevous with Rama" (large rotating cylindrical spaceship) and the short story "The Menace From Earth" (flying)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a perfect match, but there are a lot of similarities to the Niven short story "[Spirals](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66159)" (1979).  It was collected in his 1985 anthology [*Limits*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?29427).

The only major point of difference is that the story takes place in an O'Neill colony in Earth orbit, instead of flying free in space.

> We were at the center of rotation.  All around, **above and below, were fields of dirt, some plowed, some planted with grass and grains**.
>
> There were **wings attached to hooks at the entrance.**  McLeve took down a set and began strapping them on.  Black bat wings.  They made him look like a fallen angel, Milton's style.  He handed me another pair.  "Like to fly?" he asked.
>
> [...]
>
> I was a tiny chick in a vast eggshell.  **The landscape was wrapped around me: fields and houses, and layout yards of construction gear, and machinery, and vats of algae, and three huge windows opening on blackness.**  Every direction was down, millions of light years down when a window caught my attention.  For a moment that was terrifying.

Comment: DavidW:  The text you clipped reads exactly like what I remember!  I will look for "Spirals".  Thank you!